# OpenJDK-java/lang/Throwable.fillInStackTrace - awkward implementation?

Tags: java, jvm, throwable

I am trying to understand the implementation of Throwable.fillInStackTrace():

```
private static final StackTraceElement[] UNASSIGNED_STACK = new StackTraceElement[0];
[...]
private StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = UNASSIGNED_STACK;
[...]

/**
 * Fills in the execution stack trace. This method records within this
 * {@code Throwable} object information about the current state of
 * the stack frames for the current thread.
 *
 * <p>If the stack trace of this {@code Throwable} {@linkplain
 * Throwable#Throwable(String, Throwable, boolean, boolean) is not
 * writable}, calling this method has no effect.
 *
 * @return  a reference to this {@code Throwable} instance.
 * @see     java.lang.Throwable#printStackTrace()
 */
public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
    if (stackTrace != null ||
        backtrace != null /* Out of protocol state */ ) {
        fillInStackTrace(0);
        stackTrace = UNASSIGNED_STACK;
    }
    return this;
}

private native Throwable fillInStackTrace(int dummy);
```

(source [OpenJDK](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Throwable.java))

I would have guess that fillInStackTrace(int) collects the stack trace from VM internals, and then creates an array of java/lang/StackTraceElement and assigns it to the Throwable.stackTrace property.

However, the standard implementation seems to clear the value of Throwable.stackTrace directly after. When running a simple sample, the information is clearly stored in the Throwable. Sample:

```
Throwable th = new Throwable();
th.printStackTrace(); // prints the stack up to this point
```

So, where is the magic / what am I misunderstanding?

PS: what does "out of protocol state" mean in the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native `fillInStackTrace(int)` method does not create an array of `StackTraceElement` instances. It captures a snapshot of the current stack trace in an implementation specific format and stores it in the `backtrace` variable.

Only when the array of `StackTraceElement` instances is requested, the method `getOurStackTrace()` will generate the array:

```java
private synchronized StackTraceElement[] getOurStackTrace() {
    // Initialize stack trace field with information from
    // backtrace if this is the first call to this method
    if (stackTrace == UNASSIGNED_STACK ||
        (stackTrace == null && backtrace != null) /* Out of protocol state */) {
        int depth = getStackTraceDepth();
        stackTrace = new StackTraceElement[depth];
        for (int i=0; i < depth; i++)
            stackTrace[i] = getStackTraceElement(i);
    } else if (stackTrace == null) {
        return UNASSIGNED_STACK;
    }
    return stackTrace;
}
```

It’s using the helper method

```java
native StackTraceElement getStackTraceElement(int index);
```

which knows how to decode the `backtrace`.

So if the application never accesses the stacktrace, this might be cheaper than generating the full array in advance.

You have already posted the declaration of `stackTrace` which initializes the field with `UNASSIGNED_STACK`. But there is [this special constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable,boolean,boolean)) which allows to suppress stack traces altogether.

```java
protected Throwable(String message, Throwable cause,
                    boolean enableSuppression,
                    boolean writableStackTrace) {
    if (writableStackTrace) {
        fillInStackTrace();
    } else {
        stackTrace = null;
    }
    detailMessage = message;
    this.cause = cause;
    if (!enableSuppression)
        suppressedExceptions = null;
}
```

So, normally `stackTrace` should be either, `UNASSIGNED_STACK` or an actual array created by `getOurStackTrace()` or set using [`setStackTrace(StackTraceElement[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#setStackTrace(java.lang.StackTraceElement%5B%5D)).

If `stackTrace` is `null`, the `backtrace` should also be `null`, if stack traces are disabled. If this is not the case, the state is “out of protocol”, which means the throwable has not been generated using normal constructor invocation, but by native code.

Comment: I think you're right, when using debug mode, I found that `stackTrace` was initialized in `fillInStackTrace`, which should be affected by debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess does not seem to be right if we follow `fillInStackTrace` native method for a bit we can see that it [sets Throwable#backtrace](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/41ce6582674bb5d14f2edb34e40ee1d7ae7601d8/src/hotspot/share/classfile/javaClasses.cpp#L2713). The implementation looks complicated but it basicallly just strips out fillInStackTrace and the contructor calls (with can be overriden).
For the next thing keep in mind that `Throwable`

- can be serialized (no constructor call into `readObject`)
- can be created directly in the vm
- `OutOfMemoryExceptions` are preloaded (because it can not be instanciated when oom)
- `fillStackTrace` is commonly overriden and left empty in SubClasses (mostly for performance)

Then in `getOurStackTrace()` the [real stackTrace is written](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/41ce6582674bb5d14f2edb34e40ee1d7ae7601d8/src/hotspot/share/classfile/javaClasses.cpp#L2940). This was made because after contructing the exception is in a immutable state (between backtrace set but stacktrace null).

Out of protocol state refers to Throwables created without calling a constructor.

If you have further questions just ask. I really like your question :)